# Applications of Gröbner bases

Tags: abstract-algebra, applications, groebner-basis

I would like to present an application of Gröbner bases.  The audience is a class of first year graduate students who are taking first year algebra.

Does anyone have suggestions on a specific application that the audience would appreciate?

Comment: See http://www.msri.org/people/members/chillar/files/gbapplfinal.pdf

Comment: You would want to at least browse [Cox/Little/O'Shea](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/iva.html).

Comment: Also [Cox/Little/O'Shea UAG](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/uag.html).

Comment: Outside mathematics, the *actual* **industrial** application is in robotics.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Gröbner basis algorithms may be considered as nonlinear generalizations of Gaussian elimination for systems of linear equations, they have very widespread applicability. Below is a random collection of applications of Gröbner bases.

- [effective computation with (holonomic) special functions](https://specfun.inria.fr/chyzak//mgfun.html)
- [solving Diophantine equations (Pell)](https://doi.org/10.1109/SYNASC.2008.13)
- [automated geometry theorem proving.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-77356-6_8)
- [coding theory](https://projekter.aau.dk/projekter/files/32972830/thesis_15jun.pdf)
- [signal and image processing](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2004.01.008)
- [robotics](https://www.tntech.edu/cas/pdf/math/techreports/TR-2008-3.pdf)
- graph coloring problems e.g. [Sudoku puzzles](https://doi.org/10.1007/11870814_13)
- extrapolating "missing links" in palaeontology, and [phylogenetic tree construction](http://www.springerlink.com/content/n3r373447175j272/fulltext.pdf)

Comment: I was unable to fix the last link over "phylogenetic tree construction", which points to `springerlink.com`. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...

Answer (score 6):

- find intersection points of a couple of conics (pick the right coefficients to make it not so tedious to do all the manipulation)
- describing the motion of a constrained single hinged robot arm or planetary epicycles (make a cardioid from two equations)
- colorability of a graph (see [A Crash Course...](http://www.ricam.oeaw.ac.at/specsem/srs/groeb/download/BuchbergerCrashCourse.pdf) ) (when presented with the construction, very easy to see that the algorithm produces a solution)

Answer (score 6):

I learnt of a cool application here in Math.SE where I had asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27751/sketch-a-curve-given-parametrically-by-x-2t-4t3-and-t2-3t4) to parametrize $$x=2t-4t^3$$ $$y=t^2-3t^4$$

There was no straightforward way to eliminate $t$, however a [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8407/juan-joder) pointed out

> using a Gröbner basis routine such as that in *Mathematica* easily gives the implicit Cartesian equation
> $$27x^4-4x^2(36y+1)+16y(4y+1)^2=0$$
>
> In Mathematica: GroebnerBasis[{x == 2t - 4t^3, y == t^2 - 3t^4}, {x, y}, t]

I doubt this would be fascinating to graduates though.

Comment: [Somewhat similar...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199)

Answer (score 5):

Here are the things I use Grobner bases for, which I certainly find interesting:

1. Extending the univariate division algorithm to multivariate polynomials (although not a true euclidean division algorithm, it is still useful).
2. (related) Computing generators for $I_1 + I_2$ where $I_1,I_2$ are ideals in a multivariate polynomial ring (say $\mathbb{C}$), and using this to determine $I(V_1\cap V_2)$ where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are affine varieties in $\mathbb{A}^n$ for $n > 1$.

I'm not sure if these interest you or the students you are presenting to, but hopefully it's at least a start.

Comment: I don't think you need Gröbner bases to find generators for $I_1+I_2$ -- any generators of $I_1$ and of $I_2$ can be combined to give generators of $I_1+I_2$. A slightly different answer that actually uses Gröbner bases is that Gröbner bases give a way to compute generators of the intersection $I_1 \cap I_2$. (Briefly, $I_1 \cap I_2 = ((1-t)I_1 + tI_2) \cap k[x]$, and this intersection, eliminating the extra variable $t$, can be computed with Gröbner bases in an elimination order.)